# What's the most pythonic way to get name of the field when an exception related to IntegrityError is thrown?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API with DRF and I want to generate and return proper *custom* error messages when an exception related to [IntegrityError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/utils/#IntegrityError) is thrown.

To do this, I've implemented a custom exception handler. Inside the custom exception handler, I want to get the name of the field that causes the error from the [Exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/) instance and then I'll generate and return proper message in the response.

Currently, I can do this by parsing the **message** attribute of the **Exception** instance but I'm not sure this is the best possible solution.

So, is there any pythonic way to get the name of the field from the Exception instance when an exception related to IntegrityError is thrown?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you would be getting IntegrityErrors in the first place. DRF should be validating your data in the serializer, including any uniqueness constraints.

Comment: Without a custom exception handler, you're absolutely right. But I need to customise and localise error messages and handle different error types separately. (project constraints) @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1):

According to [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/_modules/django/db/utils/) it seems IntergityError is no more than an Exception so the only way is to parsing `exception.message` or `exception.args`.

You always can check what gives you `print(dir(exception))` but I'm pretty sure only `message` and `args` will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO "parsing the message" is perfectly pythonic: simple, readable, you can do the same/similar solution in any other similar situation. I've seen something like this before:

```py
# in a custom Serializer's create() method
try:
    return super().create(validated_data)
except IntegrityError as e:
    raise APIException(detail=e.args[0].split('DETAIL:  ')[1])
```

It simple, it works and getting the extra data in any other way will likely involve something significantly more complicated.